# R-Plot (Time Series)

Tags: r, graph, plot, time-series

I have groups of record in my csv file. I want to create multiple graph in same window with different color for different groups. For Example, I have `N1` record of group `A` at different timepoint and `N2` for `B` at different time points. I want to have two graphs in same window with red and green color. Is it possible? Is it possible to give the option "group by" in below example (This example worked fine for me for one set)?

```
plot(as.Date(Lines$TIMEPOINT), Lines$RESULT_VALUE, xlab="Time In Week.", 
     ylab= "Result Value AT Specific Week.", type='l', col='red')
```

I saw there are different kinds of graph but this method was very simple. Thanks in advance for your help.

============================>
@jbaums,
Your code is working fine with that data frame. But when I tried as below in real environment, though my result was good but color for the both graph was same. Am I doing any mistyping? I tried to fix my level best but no luck!

```
Input_Data3 <- Input_Data2[,c("BTCH_NBR","TIMEPOINT","RESULT_VALUE")]
plot(Input_Data3[, 2:3], type='n')

sapply(unique(Input_Data3$BTCH_NBR), function(i) {
Input_Data4 <- subset(Input_Data3, BTCH_NBR==i, select=2:3)
points(Input_Data4[order(Input_Data4$TIMEPOINT), ], col=i, type='o', pch=20)
})
legend('bottomright', legend=unique(Input_Data3$BTCH_NBR), bty='n', lty=1,   col=seq_along(unique(Input_Data3$BTCH_NBR)), pch=20)
})
```

[image: Same color for two graph]

and second issue is: legand is in red color but line graph is in pink. Any response will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You are much more likely to get useful feedback if you provide a reproducible example. We don't know what your `Lines$TIMEPOINT` etc. look like - consider including a small sample dataset (e.g. edit your question and add the output of `dput(head(Lines))`, assuming it's a data frame.

Comment: ==>1. Lines - is the name of data frame converted from my input csv file.
==>2. TIMEPOINT - is the column name which contain the value of time (in week).
==>3. RESULT_VALUE - ic the value of container at specific time (at specific week).

Comment: ==>1. Lines - is the name of data frame converted from my input csv file.
==>2. TIMEPOINT - is the column name which contain the value of time (in week).
==>3. RESULT_VALUE - is the column name which contain the value of container at specific time (at specific week).
==>4. AS_group - is teh column name which associate the group name.

Note - A group will contain many record, I mean different value of container (RESULT_VALUE) at different time interval. So one graph for one group.

Comment: ==> AS_group TIMEPOINT RESULT_VALUE
A 4 696537
A 5 718748
B 4 799355
A 1 805800
C 5 701262
B 1 531579
A 6 690068
C 7 756947
B 8 718757
A 2 701768
C 3 820113
C 6 645259

Comment: Please find the output of ("dput(head(Lines))") ===>> > dput(head(Lines))
structure(list(AS_group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("A",
"B", "C"), class = "factor"), TIMEPOINT = c(4L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L,
1L), RESULT_VALUE = c(696537L, 718748L, 799355L, 805800L, 701262L,
531579L)), .Names = c("AS_group", "TIMEPOINT", "RESULT_VALUE"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
>

Comment: @Piyush When people ask for more information, please edit your original question rather than adding additional comments. It is more difficult to read and properly format comments.

Comment: Sure.. I will take care. I am new to this forum. So learning slowly-2. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach that will iterate through all groups:

```
Lines <- structure(list(AS_group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L), 
                                         .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                                         class = "factor"), 
                    TIMEPOINT = c(4L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 1L), 
                    RESULT_VALUE = c(696537L, 718748L, 799355L, 805800L, 
                                     701262L, 531579L)), 
               .Names = c("AS_group", "TIMEPOINT", "RESULT_VALUE" ), 
               row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

plot(Lines[, 2:3], type='n')
sapply(unique(Lines$AS_group), function(i) {
  Line <- subset(Lines, AS_group==i, select=2:3)
  points(Line[order(Line$TIMEPOINT), ], col=i, type='o', pch=20)
})
legend('bottomright', legend=unique(Lines$AS_group), bty='n', 
       lty=1, col=seq_along(unique(Lines$AS_group)), pch=20)
```

[image]

Note that in this small subset of your data (the first 6 rows), there is only one instance of `C`, so for that group only a single point is plotted, with no line.

See `?plot`, `?for`, `?subset`, `?points` and `?legend` for further info.

Comment: Jbaums, Thank you soo much for such a nice help. I am looking for exact same graph. I test your code and it running fine. Again thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is Lines and you have group variable of A and B, you need something like:

```
par(mfrow = c(2,1))
plot(as.Date(Lines$TIMEPOINT[Lines$group == 'A']), Lines$RESULT_VALUE[Lines$group == 'A'], xlab= "Time In Week.", ylab= "Result Value AT Specific Week.", type='l', col='red')
plot(as.Date(Lines$TIMEPOINT[Lines$group == 'B']), Lines$RESULT_VALUE[Lines$group == 'B'], xlab= "Time In Week.", ylab= "Result Value AT Specific Week.", type='l', col='green')
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am getting following error: ==> > plot(as.Date(Lines$TIMEPOINT[Lines$As_group == 'A']), Lines$RESULT_VALUE[Lines$As_group == 'A'], xlab= "Time In Week.", ylab= "Result Value AT Specific Week.", type='l', col='red')
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
>

Comment: ==> Now this error gone. I did some typo and that produced above error.

Comment: ==> Is it possible to draw these two graph in single plot with different color?

Comment: Use `add=TRUE` in the second `plot` call (or change the second `plot` to `lines`) to overlay the plots. (I'm not sure that `as.Date` really makes sense for your data, though.)